# How to remove package from rpm database

Tags: centos6, yum, rpm

I have a `Centos 6` server that I accidentally added a `RHEL 7` package to it's rpm database.

Added wrong package

```
sudo rpm -ivh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.0/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```

So when I tried to add the correct package I get:

```
sudo rpm -ivh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/rhel/6/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.2-1.el6.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/rhel/6/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.2-1.el6.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.rzDcOd: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID a14fe591: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-ZABBIX from install of zabbix-release-3.2-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package zabbix-release-3.0-1.el7.noarch
    file /etc/yum.repos.d/zabbix.repo from install of zabbix-release-3.2-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package zabbix-release-3.0-1.el7.noarch
```

So I ran the following:

```
yum clean all
rpm --rebuilddb
```

Then added RHEL 6 package:

```
sudo rpm -ivh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/rhel/6/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.2-1.el6.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/rhel/6/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.2-1.el6.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.DgETOM: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID a14fe591: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:zabbix-release         ########################################### [100%]
```

But install still reverts back to wrong package:

```
sudo yum install zabbix-agent
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                                                      |  18 kB     00:00     
 * base: repos-va.psychz.net
 * epel: mirror.vcu.edu
 * extras: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * fasttrack: mirror.fileplanet.com
 * updates: mirror.fileplanet.com
base                                                                                                                                                                               | 3.7 kB     00:00     
base/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                    | 4.7 MB     00:01     
centos-sclo-rh                                                                                                                                                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00     
centos-sclo-rh/primary_db                                                                                                                                                          | 1.2 MB     00:00     
centos-sclo-sclo                                                                                                                                                                   | 2.9 kB     00:00     
centos-sclo-sclo/primary_db                                                                                                                                                        | 154 kB     00:00     
cr                                                                                                                                                                                 | 3.3 kB     00:00     
cr/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                      | 1.2 kB     00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                                               | 4.7 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                    | 6.0 MB     00:02     
extras                                                                                                                                                                             | 3.4 kB     00:00     
extras/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                  |  27 kB     00:00     
fasttrack                                                                                                                                                                          | 2.9 kB     00:00     
fasttrack/primary_db                                                                                                                                                               | 9.9 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                            | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                 | 3.0 MB     00:00     
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package zabbix-agent.x86_64 0:3.0.24-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: zabbix-agent-3.0.24-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-agent-3.0.24-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-agent-3.0.24-1.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: zabbix-agent-3.0.24-1.el7.x86_64 (zabbix)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: zabbix-agent-3.0.24-1.el7.x86_64 (zabbix)
           Requires: systemd
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
libmodule-10.0.1.274-b10_0_1_274.x86_64 has missing requires of libodbc.so.1()(64bit)
[root@medherent ~]# sudo rpm -evh zabbix-release-3.0-1.el7.noarch
rpm: --hash (-h) may only be specified during package installation
[root@medherent ~]# sudo rpm -ev zabbix-release-3.0-1.el7.noarch
error: package zabbix-release-3.0-1.el7.noarch is not installed
```

So I tried to explicitly remove package:

```
sudo rpm -ev zabbix-release-3.0-1.el7.noarch
error: package zabbix-release-3.0-1.el7.noarch is not installed
```

> How do I run YUM install to use RHEL 6 package or remove RHEL 7 package from rpm db?

**Edit**

So I ran the following per suggestion:

```
rpm -e zabbix-release
```

Which appears to have executed without error.

I don't know which packages are part of my distro:

```
ls -all /etc/yum.repos.d 
total 68 
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Jan 23 13:43 . drwxr-xr-x. 117 root root 12288 Jan 23 11:37 ..
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  1991 Jun 26  2018 CentOS-Base.repo
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   509 Sep 25  2011 CentOS-CR.repo
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   647 Jun 26  2018 CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   276 May 12  2014 CentOS-fasttrack.repo
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   289 Aug  3  2015 CentOS-fasttrack.repo.rpmnew
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   630 Jun 26  2018 CentOS-Media.repo
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   916 May 23  2016 CentOS-SCLo-scl.repo
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   892 Jun 16  2016 CentOS-SCLo-scl-rh.repo
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  8854 Jun 26  2018 CentOS-Vault.repo
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   954 Oct  3  2016 epel.repo
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  1056 Nov  4  2012 epel-testing.repo
```

**Edit 2**

Yum is still trying to use the wrong package

```
sudo yum install zabbix-agent
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirror.vcu.edu
 * extras: mirrors.greenmountainaccess.net
 * fasttrack: packages.oit.ncsu.edu
 * updates: mirror.cisp.com
base                                                                                                                                                                               | 3.7 kB     00:00     
base/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                    | 4.7 MB     00:02     
centos-sclo-rh                                                                                                                                                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00     
centos-sclo-rh/primary_db                                                                                                                                                          | 1.2 MB     00:02     
centos-sclo-sclo                                                                                                                                                                   | 2.9 kB     00:00     
centos-sclo-sclo/primary_db                                                                                                                                                        | 154 kB     00:00     
cr                                                                                                                                                                                 | 3.3 kB     00:00     
cr/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                      | 1.2 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                                             | 3.4 kB     00:00     
extras/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                  |  27 kB     00:00     
fasttrack                                                                                                                                                                          | 2.9 kB     00:00     
fasttrack/primary_db                                                                                                                                                               | 9.9 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                            | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                 | 3.0 MB     00:01     
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package zabbix-agent.x86_64 0:3.0.24-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: zabbix-agent-3.0.24-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-agent-3.0.24-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-agent-3.0.24-1.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: zabbix-agent-3.0.24-1.el7.x86_64 (zabbix)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: zabbix-agent-3.0.24-1.el7.x86_64 (zabbix)
           Requires: systemd
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
libmodule-10.0.1.274-b10_0_1_274.x86_64 has missing requires of libodbc.so.1()(64bit)
```

In particular

```
---> Package zabbix-agent.x86_64 0:3.0.24-1.el7 will be installed
```

Comment: It looks like you got lucky and all the inappropriate repos are gone.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I still cannot get the correct version to install.  Please see my edit 2

Comment: You should clean all of yum's caches with `yum clean all`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  I did that after running rpm -e zabbix-release and removing the /etc/zabbix direcory and then rebooted machine in that order.  yum still uses wrong repo.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Is there a way to instruct yum to use a specific repo?  I want/need it to use http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/rhel/6/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.2-1.el6.noarch.rpm  which is for CentOS 6.

Comment: You should be able to install that RPM directly. But I still don't see where yum is getting an el7 zabbix repo from.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Thank you, installing directly with rpm working.  Please move to answer. :^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to uninstall the incorrectly installed package, i.e.:

```
rpm -e zabbix-release
```

You remove packages by *package name*, not by *filename*, because installed packages don't have a filename.

---

Of course, this probably won't fix the problem, because you destroyed and rebuilt the RPM database when there was no need to do so, and it is likely there are files the wrong package installed that are no longer tracked. You will need to find these and remove them manually. Look in the `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory and find repo files which don't correspond to your distribution. Or you might get lucky and the files get cleaned out OK.

---

Once that's done, you need to clean yum's caches with `yum clean all` and then reinstall the correct zabbix-release RPM.

Comment: This is answer when combined with directly installing rpm, rather than using package name - package name always referenced incorrect rpm.

Comment: @RoyHinkley You _install_ a downloaded RPM file using the filename of the file containing the package.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants to actually *just* remove the rpm from the rpm database, such as in the case of incorrect dependency mappings, you can use the following command:

`rpm -e --justdb packagename`

**NB: This is NOT the correct normal way to uninstall a package and should be an absolute last resort**

This will remove the entry from rpmdb immediately, but any files created by the installation of that rpm will still exist on your system, which can mean many different things, depending on what that package was. If it's a kernel module or a daemon or something else that runs automatically, it will continue to do so, because you have not actually uninstalled it.

Source:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/186933

Comment: Thanks this is what worked when I in a hurry deleted the folder of my installation BEFORE running the rpm -e. 
Note: in RHEL8

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps and hope will resolve the issue -

```sh
# rpm -e zabbix-release
```

Now, install the package you want to install and follow below steps.

```sh
# yum info zabbix-release 
# yum list zabbix-release
```

This will clear from your yum cache also.

```sh
# yum clean zabbix-release
# yum clean all
# yum install zabbix-agent
```